# 2d quadrature weights for an arbitrary set of nodes

Tags: quadrature

I need to estimate the value of a 2d integral

$\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}dy \int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dx \, f(x,y) P(x,y)$

I have the an explicit analytical form for $P(x,y)$.
I have samples of the function $f(x,y)$ at a set of nodes $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1...n$, with $n \approx 100$, and no repetitions. The points are not distributed in the $xy$ plane according to any known quadrature scheme.

Assuming the value of the integral can be represented by the quadrature formula

$I \approx \sum w_{i} f(x_i,y_i) P(x_i,y_i)$

I would like to know if there is a procedure to calculate the weights $w_{i}$ associated to the set of nodes $(x_i,y_i)$.

I know that such a procedure exists in 1d (see, e.g., [1](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/toms655_original/toms655_original.html)),

but what about 2D? Any code or reference will be very much appreciated.